# How to set a layout gravity center

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

I am just designing a layout for login. However, I want to set a layout gravity center (full layout content set into the center of the screen). I am using gravity center but it doesn't give me the proper output, So may be I am having problem with another issue. Bellow is my layout xml code. Hence, Can someone suggest me where I am having problem !!!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#458221"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
   <!-- I want to set this layout into the center of the screen ,This layout cann't set the gravity center -->


        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Name: "
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="user"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="password"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="pass"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: lots of nesting. bad performance alert. And what exactly do you mean by center? vertically, horizontally or at screen?

Comment: I just add two layout into a single layout. So Why it is bad performance alert. If you give me some information about that, I will get benefited. What ever thank you

Comment: you have a single child textview inside linear layout, you must avoid such nestings as findviewbyid gets costlier with every nesting

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a relative layout. You can then user `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` to center in the parent horizontally and vertically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your root element `FrameLayout` or `RelativeLayout` like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#458221"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center" >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Name: "
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="user"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="password"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="pass"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

change gravity to this :

```
 android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
```

it should solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

You just add `android:gravity="center"` to the top most parent Linear Layout like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:background="#458221"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Name: "
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="user"
            />
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="password"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="pass"
            />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**android:gravity** -
Gravity for the view associated with these LayoutParams.

**android:layout_gravity** - Standard gravity constant that a child supplies to its parent. Defines how the child view should be positioned, on both the X and Y axes, within its enclosing layout.

Answer (score 0):

**android:layout_gravity**

`android:layout_gravity` is used to set the position of an element in its **paren**t (e.g. a child View inside a Layout). Supported by `LinearLayout` and `FrameLayout`

**android:gravity**

`android:gravity` is used to set the position of content **inside** an element (e.g. a text inside a TextView).

to get and idea copy this XML and understand how it works

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/first"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/second"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/third"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/first"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/second"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/third"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/first"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="left"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/second"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="@dimen/fixed"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/third"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:gravity="right"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```